# Extracting a row from a table from a url

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to download EPS value for all years (Under Annual Trends) from the below link.
http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=500180&expandable=0

I tried using Beautiful Soup as mentioned in the below answer.
[Extracting table contents from html with python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196018/extracting-table-contents-from-html-with-python-and-beautifulsoup)
But couldn't proceed after the below code. I feel I am very close to my answer. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/stockreach_financials.aspx?scripcode=500180&expandable=0").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table',{'id' :'acr'})
#the below code wasn't working as I expected it to be
tr = table.find('tr', text='EPS')
```

I am open to using any other language to get this done

Comment: What result did you get that you were not expecting?

Comment: the object tr is empty

Answer (score 2):

The text is in the *td* not the *tr* so get the *td* using the text and then call *.parent* to get the *tr*:

```
In [12]: table = soup.find('table',{'id' :'acr'})

In [13]: tr = table.find('td', text='EPS').parent

In [14]: print(tr)
<tr><td class="TTRow_left" style="padding-left: 30px;">EPS</td><td class="TTRow_right">48.80</td>
<td class="TTRow_right">42.10</td>
<td class="TTRow_right">35.50</td>
<td class="TTRow_right">28.50</td>
<td class="TTRow_right">22.10</td>
</tr>
In [15]: [td.text for td in tr.select("td + td")]
Out[15]: [u'48.80', u'42.10', u'35.50', u'28.50', u'22.10']
```

Which you will see exactly matches what is on the page.

Another approach would be to call *find_next_siblings*:

```
In [17]: tds = table.find('td', text='EPS').find_next_siblings("td")

In [18]: tds
Out[19]: 
[<td class="TTRow_right">48.80</td>,
 <td class="TTRow_right">42.10</td>,
 <td class="TTRow_right">35.50</td>,
 <td class="TTRow_right">28.50</td>,
 <td class="TTRow_right">22.10</td>]
In [20]: [td.text for td in tds]
Out[20]: [u'48.80', u'42.10', u'35.50', u'28.50', u'22.10']
```